# NetworkCredential.Domain Property

Tags: networkcredentials

```
  MailAddress Sender = new MailAddress("SomeOne@yahoo.com", "SomeOne", Encoding.UTF8);


 SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com",465);
Client.Credentials = new  System.Net.NetworkCredential(Sender.Address,"Password",Domain??? );
```

just out of curiosity  what is the third overload of NetworkCredential
I mean what we need to pass argument for Domain property .      I searched on net but but no one used it(domain property)   .I tried "Yahoo.com","@Yahoo.com","Yahoo"  bot no  every time same authentication error .It can be done without Domain property but where can we  use it or what we can pass it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Domain` property is used for NTLM authentication with Active Directory domains.
It is not used for normal login scenarios.